# How to move Linux Swap Partition - GParted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, debian, ubuntu-16.04

I have a dual boot machine with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I want to allocate my space to my home partition but I have to move my Linux Swap Partition.

How can I do it?

Here are my partitions before I shrink C volume in windows:

Partitions before C drive shrink:

[image]

Here it's my partition now with no allocate space:

No allocated partition:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `swapoff` to deactivate the swap partition.

Note that once deactivated, the swap partition can also simply be deleted (and removed from /etc/fstab), because it really just stores temporary data. Later you can create a new empty swap partition of the desired size and activate it again.

Comment: I did that. But I can't expand the partition now... It says that I don't have free space to expand my home partition...

Answer (score 0):

The unallocated space that you have created follows partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3`
which is the Windows partition.
I assume that you wish to resize `/dev/nvme0n1p7` which is the Linux partition
of `/`.

To do that, you need to move the unallocated space to follow `/dev/nvme0n1p7`.
You can do that by moving left (up) the partitions of
`/dev/nvme0n1p6` (linux-swap) and `/dev/nvme0n1p7` itself.

Once the unallocated space follows `/dev/nvme0n1p7`, then you may extend it over
this space.

As an error during such an operation can be disastrous, I suggest to take good
backups before starting, even taking a backup image of the entire disk
(if you have enough external disk space).